# Background process text appears in terminal vim

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux

First time poster, long time lurker, searched, couldn’t find etc, etc.

I’m running vim in tmux, in iTerm2. I’m running a server with Grunt.js, which I have running in the background, out of my way. I start my grunt server in the background like this:

```
grunt server &
```

Grunt also watches a bunch of files, and runs some tasks when any of the watched files have been written to. The problem is, when I am in vim and I write a file, the output from grunt starts rendering in vim! Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem:

Before writing the file:

[image]

And after writing the file:

[image]

What have I tried?

I’ve tried running a ‘stock’ vim by starting with this:

```
vim -u NONE
```

…But the problem remains. This suggests to me that the problem is not with my `.vimrc`. Perhaps it’s an issue with iTerm2, I don’t know. Help.

Comment: Is the rogue text actually saved to the file and is still present when you reload it?

Comment: No, it’s cleared when vim redraws that region. I noticed this after disabling `lazyredraw`, and moving the cursorline over the artefacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a process as a background one does not automatically redirect its output. So what the background process sends to `stdout` or `stderr` appears in the terminal you started the process in.

### Solutions

- Redirect the output of the background process during start:
  `grunt server >grunt-server.log 2>&1 &`
- Start the background process in a separate `tmux` session.
- `nohup` automatically redirects the output to `nohup.out`:
  `nohup grunt server &`
- if you do not need the output you can discard it:
  `grunt server >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix that issue from Vim itself: `grunt` is just spitting stuff via `stdout` an that output is leaking in anything you do in that shell, Vim included. Normally, a simple `<C-l>` should cleanup the screen.

Either you find a way to silence `grunt` completely or you launch it in another iTerm pane/tab/window.